# ClassNotFound Exception for Oracle even though Class is in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I am facing a ClassNotFound Exception even though the class can be importable using the code helper for import in Eclipse. That means the class is actually accessible.

```
package com.shaurya.dbmodels;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

public class OracleSCB 
    extends DBuser 
    implements ServerConnectionBehavior {


    public OracleSCB()
    {
        super("SYSTEM","qwerty","Oracle");
    }

    public OracleSCB(String uid,String pass,String catg)
    {
        super(uid,pass,catg);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getconnection()
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionURL(),getuid(),getpass());
            return con;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
            System.out.print("test4");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error like wrong import or anything. But i cannot load the oracle driver. I know i dont need to do the **import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;** but its just to check if the driver is accessible or not, and it is.

Comment: Make sure it's in your runtime classpath too. Not only do you not need to do the import, you also don't need the `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` (as of JDBC 4).

Comment: As mentioned by Elliott, don't confuse compilation classpath vs run-time classpath. Import is going to use compilation classpath while a classnot found occurs during execution (run-time). It is likely that you don't have the Oracle jars in the run-time classpath

Comment: okay, so what if i deploy it somewhere else, who wont be having the oracle drivers in hes runtime classpath(system variables??) I have the Jar file inside the lib of the project and .classpath file contains the relative path to it too.(if thats what you mean by runtime classpath??)

Comment: Also i am using Oracle 10g with Java 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the runtime classpath for a dynamic web project is always inside the WEB-INF. So if someone wants to use another JAR it must be placed inside Web-INF/lib and then added to build path. And this does the trick